# Understanding VAO's with IBO's

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

```
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
ibo.bind(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER); //where do I put this?
glBindVertexArray(0);

while (glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED)) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glfwSwapBuffers();
}
```

The way I understand VAO is that I create a vao handle and bind it like this

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

Now I can fill it the VAO with these three commands

```
vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

I should note that I used my own vbo class here.

And then I close my VAO with

```
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

And then I can just load it in the renderloop

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

But I don't get any output.

Now I think it has something to do with my indexed array. (ibo)
How do I use a VAO with an IBO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A VAO encapuslates the vertex array pointers (including the array buffer bindings at the time of the pointer call), the enable bits and the current `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding (but not the current `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding). So the IBO bind that you do is fine at that particular position.

However, you do a `glDisableVertexAttribArray( 0 );` while the VAO is still bound, so the VAO contains that attrib array as disabled.